# Is there a way to detect the .NET version used by PowerShell 7.32 without relying on dotnet command?

Tags: powershell, .net-core

Due to a security vulnerability I need to find the version of .net that PowerShell is using on my server.  There are a number of articles that detail how to find the SDK or runtime version of .net Core.  However, those solutions don't work on my workstation or server.  I don't have the `dotnet.exe` command, and there doesn't seem to be any installation of .net on my computers, even though PowerShell 7.32 is installed.

How do I find the version of .net that PowerShell is using?

I tried a number of solutions that appear in various articles on the Internet.  However, none of them produced any results.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) is a so-called [*self-contained*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained) .NET (Core) application: That is, it comes bundled with its own, private copy of the .NET (Core) runtime.

If there's a known security vulnerability in the bundled .NET version, the only way to avoid is to upgrade to a new version *of PowerShell* that comes with a newer .NET version in which that vulnerability has been patched.

[Installing PowerShell on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows) describes options for installing PowerShell (Core) in a manner that facilitates or automates upgrading:

- via `winget` - the recommended method - which allows later upgrading on demand with `winget upgrade` (though this method actually installs the MSI package on x64/x86 machines, and should therefore result in *automatic* upgrades - see next point)
- (directly) via the MSI package, which, in version 7.3+ is integrated with MU (Microsoft Update) via automatic updates by default.

The **simplest way to determine a given PowerShell installation's underlying .NET version** is to use [`System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription):

```bash
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::FrameworkDescription
```

Note that the result is a *string*; e.g.:

```
.NET 7.0.5
```

(This also works in *Windows PowerShell* v5.1, for the *shared* version of .NET Framework that it depends on, e.g. `.NET Framework 4.8.9139.0` ; the one an only copy of Windows PowerShell on a given machine is invariably integrated with Microsoft Update; note that Windows PowerShell is no longer actively developed and receives *only* security-critical updates.)

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out that when you install PowerShell Core it does not actually install .net core as an application/SDK/runtime etc...

PowerShell just copies the .net core files to it's own folders.  In a default install the folder is located here:

`"$env:ProgramFiles\powershell\7"`

Here is a quick function to get the current version of .net core dlls that the PowerShell core installation is using if you installed it at the default location on a MS Windows platform:

```
function Get-PowerShellCoreDotNetVersion{
    return (Get-ChildItem "$env:ProgramFiles\PowerShell\7\System.Core.dll").VersionInfo | Select-Object *version*
}
```

Comment: Why do you want that in the first place? Security fixes are published for Powershell itself, usually through Windows Update.

Comment: Yes, people reacting so badly to comments is really demotivating. Don't react so badly to comments. In fact, if you really care about vulnerabilities in Powershell you should ask at serverfault.com, the Admin equivalent of StackOverflow.

Comment: You made an assumption that somehow the version of .NET would affect PowerShell. You could end up patching .NET while leaving Powershell vulnerable. As for the copy of .NET inside Powershell, that's a self-contained deployment. You can publish your own applications as self-contained if you want. If you do, it's up to you to update the runtime if something happens

Comment: You can generalize and simplify that path with `$PSHOME`: `(Get-ChildItem $PSHOME/System.Core.dll).VersionInfo | Select-Object *version*`